# Conditions on the sets comprising a union for the union to be an infinite set

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

I have the following union of sets: $\{n\in\mathbb{N}: t-\epsilon<s_n<t\}\cup \{n\in\mathbb{N}: t<s_n<t+\epsilon\}$. In order for this union to be infinite for all $\epsilon>0$, must it be the case that at least one of the two sets comprising the union must also be infinite *for all $\epsilon>0$*? My intuition is that, indeed, at least one of the two sets must be infinite, and that, additionally, they must be infinite for all $\epsilon>0$. Otherwise the set formed by their union cannot be infinite for all $\epsilon>0$. Is this reasoning correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let$$L_\varepsilon=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid t-\varepsilon<s_n<t\}\quad\text{and}\quad R_\varepsilon=\{n\in\mathbb{N}\mid t<s_n<t+\varepsilon\}$$and that $L_\varepsilon\cup R_\varepsilon$ is infinite for every $\varepsilon>0$. If $L_{\varepsilon_1}$ is finite for some $\varepsilon_1>0$ and if $R_{\varepsilon_2}$ is finite for some $\varepsilon_2>0$, take $\varepsilon\in\left(0,\min\left\{\varepsilon_1,\varepsilon_2\right\}\right)$. Then, since $L_\varepsilon\subset L_{\varepsilon_1}$ and since $L_{\varepsilon_1}$ is finite, $L_\varepsilon$ is finite. And, since $R_\varepsilon\subset R_{\varepsilon_2}$ and since $R_{\varepsilon_2}$ is finite, $R_\varepsilon$ is finite. But then $L_\varepsilon\cup R_\varepsilon$ is finite too.

So, yes, if $L_\varepsilon\cup R_\varepsilon$ is infinite for *every* $\varepsilon>0$, then $L_\varepsilon$ is infinite for every $\varepsilon>0$ or $R_\varepsilon$ is infinite for every $\varepsilon>0$.